# What is the correct order to create a ALB for a ECS service?

Tags: amazon-elb, amazon-ecs

I have created a number of ecs services this way, but I find that from time to time I struggle to get everything right. I want to get some feedback from the community if there is any issues with the following steps:

**Backgroud**:

The ecs cluster creates instances on a non-default VPC

**Steps**:

1. Create a new task. Map port 0 to the exposed port 8080
2. Create an new Application Load Balancer. Make sure it use the right
       target vpc
3. Create a service in the cluster. Choose the ALB as created in the
       previous. Add the target group to the load balancer.
4. Go to the relevant security group and make sure port 0-65535 of
       inbound traffic are allowed

   Does the above steps make sense to you? Can they be further streamlined?

Comment: *"Go to the relevant security group and make sure port 0-65535 of inbound traffic are allowed"*  Why 0-65535?  Wouldn't this just be 8080? Or whatever port your service is bound/mapped to?  Inbound security groups are only interested in the target port.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot ECS uses ephemeral ports, though http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_PortMapping.html states it will use 49153+, certainly 32768+. No reason to expose 22 unnecessarily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#4 should be done first as it'll cause tasks to appear unhealthy if the ALB cannot reach the container.

#2,3 are in the correct order, then #1 can be done before or after 2,3.